# Assigning value to input in ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I want to assign value to input field. When I `console.log` I get the output as title is welocme to the app. Content is hello world. But only welcome is assigned to title input and only hello is assigned to content input. Only the first word is assigned. Please help.

**post.ejs**

```
<%- include('./partials/header');-%>
<%- include('./partials/flash');-%>

<form action="/posts/<%= post._id %>/edited" method="POST">
  <%= console.log("title is "+post.Title +" ."+"content is "+post.Content); %>
  <h1><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=<%= post.Title %>></h1>
  <p><input type="text" name="content" id="content" value=<%= post.Content %>></p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>

<%- include('./partials/footer');-%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose ejs variable inside quotes.

```
//enclose like this
value="<%= post.Title %>"
value="<%= post.Content %>"

<h1><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<%= post.Title %>"></h1>
<p><input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="<%= post.Content %>"></p>
```